# AngularJS and Laravel config for nginx. Running php from url segment

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, nginx

I have problem configuring laravel configuration that would run from /api/ segment of main domain.
Idea is to serve at subdomain.domain.com main Angular aplication and in subdomain.domain.com/api/ laravel php server configuration.

**UPDATE #1**

I have managed to run laravel from /api/ segment with this configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    root /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/client/monkey/dist;

    access_log /var/www/subdomain.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/subdomain.domain.com.error.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    index index.php index.html;

    location /  {

        root /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/client/monkey/dist;
        index index.html;
        if (!-e $request_filename){ # handles page reload
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
        }
    }

    location /api/ {
        root /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/server/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ /api/.+\.php$ {

        root /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/server/;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$  /$1  break;

        fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_param                   MONKEY_ENV production;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        # fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    }
}
```

Only problem that has left is that when i'm using subdomain.domain.com/api/segment1/segment... then I need to add in routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    // my routes settings
});
```

**As laravel is starting from suddomain.domain.com/ as root path. How can i rewrite /api/ so that laravel takes /api/ as routing starting point ?**

Comment: Are you using Laravel for anything _outside_ `/api`? If not then why are you not making `/api` the public folder for Laravel?

Comment: /api path is only for laravel, cause this is my backend that laravel handles. So if i rename /server to /api it should work ? Do i need to remove any of rules in config or add extra rules ?

Answer (score 1):

If I hava understanded your problem, I guess that you could solve this with the ***alias* directive** instead *root*. Using the *root* directive Nginx just takes de informed *location* and concat it at the end of the informed root path.

So, in your case, this conf:

```
location /api/ {
   root /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/server/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

nginx would resolved it to `/var/www/subdomain.domain.com/server/api` as the final path.

Using the ***alias*** directive, this conf,

```
location /api {
   alias /var/www/subdomain.domain.com/server/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

would be resolved to anything that's aim to '/api' but nginx is not concatening the 'api' string in the final path it uses.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Hopes this helps.